# Javascript RegExp - test Method issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an issue in implementing Javascript RegExp - test Method.

```
var array = ['facebook', 'twitter', 'linkedin', 'xing', 'weibo']

array .forEach(function(cns) {
    var connector_name = '/.*' + cns + '$/';
    console.log('conne name', connector_name);
    if (connector_name.test('facebook')) {
        con = {
            account_type: cns
        };
        console.log('cns', cns);
    }

});
```

it gives me uncaughtException *** [TypeError: Object /.*facebook$/ has no method 'test'].
but when i give following way it works

```
if (/.*facebook$/.test('facebook')) {
con = {
    account_type: 'facebook'
    };
}
```

Please help me to fix this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

> `var connector_name = '/.*' + cns + '$/';`

There `connector_name` is a String, not a RegExp object. And `String` does not have the `test()` method.

But here:

> `if (/.*facebook$/.test('facebook')) {`

`/.*facebook$/` is a RegExp object, which has the `test()` method.

What you want to use is the RegExp constructor:

```
var array = ['facebook', 'twitter', 'linkedin', 'xing', 'weibo']

array .forEach(function(cns) {
    var connector_name = new RegExp('.*' + cns + '$');
    console.log('conne name', connector_name);
    if (connector_name.test(facebook)) {
        con = {
            account_type: cns
        };
        console.log('cns', cns);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a regular expression like this:

```
/regular expression/
```

… or like this:

```
new RegExp('regular expression')
```

You cannot create one using a string like this:

```
'/.*' + cns + '$/';
```

**Snippet:**

```js
var array = ['facebook', 'twitter', 'linkedin', 'xing', 'weibo']

array .forEach(function(cns) {
  var connector_name = new RegExp('.*' + cns + '$');
  console.log('conne name', connector_name);
  if (connector_name.test('facebook')) {
    con = {
      account_type: cns
    };
    console.log('cns', cns);
  }
});
```